# How can I get a terminal output, seperate it into lines and enter it into a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list

How can I get the output of "service --status-all" from the terminal and enter it into a list of list? (each list contains a line)

I have tried this code:

```
a  = os.popen('service --status-all').readlines()
    print a
    string=str(a)
    str=string.split('\n')
```

but it does not allow me to seperate the lines for some reason.
how can I do this?

thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you want. `a` is already a list of lines. Try `for line in a: print line` to see for yourself.

Comment: The `readlines` function already separates your input stream into a `list` of lines.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine on my system. `a` is a list in which each element is a line of the command output. Can you show the output of this program you are getting (along with the one which you expected instead) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `splitlines` method to split output by lines

> str.splitlines([keepends]) Return a list of the lines in the string,
>   breaking at line boundaries. This method uses the universal newlines
>   approach to splitting lines. Line breaks are not included in the
>   resulting list unless keepends is given and true.
>
> For example, 'ab c\n\nde fg\rkl\r\n'.splitlines() returns ['ab c', '',
>   'de fg', 'kl'], while the same call with splitlines(True) returns ['ab
>   c\n', '\n', 'de fg\r', 'kl\r\n'].
>
> Unlike split() when a delimiter string sep is given, this method
>   returns an empty list for the empty string, and a terminal line break
>   does not result in an extra line.

This method will run shell command and return list of the lines:

```
def run_shell_command_multiline(cmd):
        p = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError("%r failed, status code %s stdout %r stderr %r" % (
                cmd, p.returncode, stdout, stderr))
        return stdout.splitlines()  # This is the stdout from the shell command
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `.readlines()` **already** breaks your output into lines.

If you want to get rid of the additional `\n`, you can also use `.strip()`.

```
import os

a = os.popen('service --status-all').readlines()
output = [el.strip() for el in a]

print(output)

# ['first line', 'second line', 'third line']
```